# Create new column in dataframe by passing existing pandas column values as argument to API call

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apply

I have created a function below, get_lyrics, which I want to pass the Song_Title and Singer_Name column values from an existing dataframe and create a new column in the dataframe.

My code below that attempts to create a column `df['Lyrics']` gives me this error below and I have no idea why:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

My testing of the function with `get_lyrics(test_song_name, test_song_author)` works, it returns a very long string.

```
import lyricsgenius as lg 
import pandas as pd     
genius = lg.Genius(access_token=token)

test_song_name = "My Heart Will Go On"
test_song_author = "Celine Dion"
 
def get_lyrics(Song_Title, Singer_Name):
    song = genius.search_song(Song_Title, Singer_Name)
    return song.lyrics
        
get_lyrics(test_song_name, test_song_author)

df['Lyrics'] = df.apply(
    get_lyrics(
    df["Song_Title"], df["Singer_Name"]
    ) 
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To apply function on rows, you can use `apply()` with `axis=1`.

```py
df['Lyrics'] = df.apply(lambda row: get_lyrics(row["Song_Title"], row["Singer_Name"]), axis=1)
```

Or with lambda function in one line

```py
df['Lyrics'] = df.apply(lambda row: genius.search_song(row["Song_Title"], row["Singer_Name"]).lyrics, axis=1)
```

If you don't want lambda, you can do

```py
def get_lyrics(row):
    song = genius.search_song(row["Song_Title"], row["Singer_Name"])
    return song.lyrics

df['Lyrics'] = df.apply(genius.search_song, axis=1)
```

Comment: Both of those solutions lambda functions, not just latter. Is there a way to do without? If not that's OK, the lambda syntax is not that much extra.

Comment: @user2415706 See my edited answer. Yours is also ok by unpacking the row.

Answer (score 0):

I found this page here: https://www.codeforests.com/2020/07/18/pass-multiple-columns-to-lambda/

That has two working solutions. The first is identical to that posted by @Ynjxsjmh

```
df["Lyrics"] = df.apply(lambda x : 
get_lyrics(x["Song_Title"], x["Singer_Name"]), axis=1
)
```

This latter one first selects a subset of the dataframe columns and then unpacks them with *x to feed into get_lyrics.

```
df["Lyrics"] = df[["Song_Title", "Singer_Name"]].apply(lambda x: 
get_lyrics(*x),
axis=1)
```